# Is there a plan to support MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext in NLog for Dotnet standard?

Tags: nlog, .net-standard

Looking at the current code of NLog 5.0.0,  https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/5.0.0-beta05-test/src/NLog/MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.cs, it won't support MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext for .Net standard.
So, I have a few related questions:

1. Why is it not supported?
2. Would it be in .net standard 2.0 ?
3. What should I use instead? The MappedDiagnosticContext does not support all the async features as far as I know.

Thanks.

Comment: Better to look at this branch (Used for NLog 5.0 BETA07): https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/coreCLR/src/NLog/MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.cs

Comment: IMO these kind of questions are better suited to ask in a GitHub issue. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rolf, I got my answers, so just sharing :-)
Looking at the branch coreCLR from NLog https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/coreCLR/src/NLog/MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.cs, MappedDiagnosticLogicalContext is fully supported starting with .Net Standard 1.3.
I tested it by download the 5.0.0-beta07 beta version:

```
PM> install-package NLog -Pre
...
Successfully installed 'NLog 5.0.0-beta07' to ClassLibrary1
...
```

And there is it:

```
 NLog.MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set(key, value);
```